# Test if type pointed to by KeyPath is a Set

Tags: swift, generics, swift-keypath

Given a `KeyPath<Root, Value>`, is there a clean way to test if `Value.self` is a `Set`? For Core Data, I want to specify an API that takes a `KeyPath<Root, Value>`, and can use this to determine if it's a `toMany` relationship. My best attempt thus far was to specify a protocol:

```swift
extension CollectionQueryable {

    var isToMany: Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

Then, have all `KeyPath`s conform to it:

```swift
extension KeyPath: CollectionQueryable { }
```

Then conditionally return `true` for the two cases that are valid: `NSOrderedSet` and `Set`.

```swift
extension KeyPath where Value == NSOrderedSet {

    var isToMany: Bool {
        return true
    }
}

extension KeyPath where Value: Set {

    var isToMany: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

But the compiler is complaining that I'm not specifying the generic type of the `Set` here. If I switch this to `Collection`, the compiler is quite happy, but this won't work because it returns `true` when `Value` is a `String` which is quite wrong in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You could inverse how the generics are injected by using overloaded functions. This will allow you to avoid the missing generics problem, and also has the benefit of being explicit behaviourally speaking.

```swift
func isToMany<Root, Value>(_ keyPath: KeyPath<Root, Value>) -> Bool {
    return false
}

func isToMany<Root>(_ keyPath: KeyPath<Root, NSOrderedSet>) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func isToMany<Root, Element>(_ keyPath: KeyPath<Root, Set<Element>>) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a type-erasure technique found on one of the `Optional` posts to achieve what I wanted given only `Type` information:

```swift
protocol ToManyProtocol {
    static var elementType: Any.Type { get }
}

extension Set: ToManyProtocol {
    static var elementType: Any.Type {
        return Element.self
    }
}
```

Now I can test if something is `toMany` by testing whether the Type is `ToManyProtocol`:

```swift
var isToMany: Bool {
    return Value.self is ToManyProtocol.Type
}
```